# How to fire events (custom event) from view and handle them in controller in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I am using Ext JS MVC and i want to fire an event from the View and Controller must handle that.

I have a filefield in a view and when ever i change/select a file using that, i want to populate the grid with contents of the file in each row for every line in text file.

So how to setup the event and listen to them in controller.

say the event is named 'onLoadingTextFile', how can i listen to this event in Controller and handle the event by calling a method in controller and populate the grid.

```
         {
            xtype : 'filefield',
            buttonText : 'Load text file',

            listeners : {
                'change' : function(field, value) {
                    var file = field.getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                        var fileContent = oFREvent.target.result;
                        //fire an event 
                    };
                    filecontent = reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }
```

And in controller i want something like

```
    init : function() {
        this.control({
            // I want something as follows
            'viewport > container' : {
                'onLoadingTextFile' : this.onLoadingTextFile
            }
        });
    },

    onLoadingTextFile : function(fileContent) {
        //populate grid with fileContent
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in http://mutinyworks.com/blog/2012/05/15/extjs-and-a-simple-mvc-model-view-controller-tutorial-part-2/
ExtJS provides a clean way to do this, I am new to ExtJS so it was a bit difficult to follow up with the concepts.

If an event can be handled in view, than it can always be controlled by controller (atleast for the events provided by ExtJS).

Here in this case 'filefield' of ExtJS has event 'change' so the code becomes something as below

```
{
    xtype : 'filefield',
    buttonText : 'Load text file',
}
```

and controller can be changed like

```
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'filefield' : {
            'change' : this.onLoadingTextFile
        }
    });
},

onLoadingTextFile : function(field, value) {
    //populate grid with fileContent
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I looked at your question, but I didn't have the time. Glad you found it yourself.